# Cannot Draw a triangle without VAO on MacOS

Tags: opengl, vertex-buffer, vertex-arrays

So I was watching [Cherno's Video on Vertex attributes](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=x0H--CL2tUI&list=LLQ6dYv5lcF09QrqDlxMZpzQ&index=385) and he was successful in drawing a triangle without a VAO, but in tutorials from learnopengl.com they specifically say they we need a VAO to draw VBO and I tested it and it works fine.[image]
Here is my snippet :

```
//==============================================================================
// glGenVertexArrays(1, &VAO);
// glBindVertexArray(VAO);

glGenBuffers(1, &VBO);
glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, VBO);
glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sizeof(triangleVertices), triangleVertices, GL_STATIC_DRAW);

glVertexAttribPointer(0, 3, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, 3 * sizeof(GLfloat), (GLvoid*)0);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(0);

//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
// Game Loop
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
/* Loop until the user closes the window */
while (!glfwWindowShouldClose(window))
{
    /* Poll for and process events */
    glfwPollEvents();

    /* Render here */
    glClearColor(0.2f, 0.3f, 0.3f, 1.0f);   // RGBA
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    glUseProgram(shaderProgram);
    // glBindVertexArray(VAO);// we did not unbind it so it's still binded to the assigned      VAO
    glDrawArrays(GL_TRIANGLES, 0, 3);


    /* Swap front and back buffers */
    glfwSwapBuffers(window);
}
//-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

This only works if I uncomment the VAO which is understandable, what I can't get my head around is how did Cherno got it working without a VAO and just using a VBO? Is it a MacOS specific thing?

Answer (score 1):

Above a certain GL version Macs only support OpenGL core profiles, which require VAOs. This is perfectly legal, but it does mean that code written for other platforms, where compatibility profiles are allowed, may not port.

Answer (score 0):

I am also a beginner and it looks like we're studying on the same document. To render a triangle using VBO alone, just comment out these three lines of code (this approach may not be normative)

```cpp
// glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MAJOR, 3);
// glfwWindowHint(GLFW_CONTEXT_VERSION_MINOR, 3);
// glfwWindowHint(GLFW_OPENGL_PROFILE, GLFW_OPENGL_CORE_PROFILE);
```